# FileReader sometimes works and sometimes not with cordova

Tags: html, cordova, uglifyjs, html5-filesystem

The method `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` does not execute the handlers and no gives no error.

The problem occurs sometimes, not in runtime, but when I runs the r.js proccess (with grunt `grunt-contrib-requirejs`).

It's very strange.

The code is:

```
CoFS.prototype.readFromFileObject = function (file, callback) {                                                                         
    var self = this;

    this._log("Creating filereader object", file);
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        self._log("load end call! with large (relative): ", this.result.length );

        if (!this.result) return null;

        var Buf  = arrayBufferToBuffer(this.result);

        callback(null, Buf);
    };

    reader.onerror = function (ev) {
        self._log("Error Reading file", ev);
        callback(new Error('Reading file'));
    };

    reader.onabort = function (ev) {
        self._log("Reading file Abort!!");
        callback(new Error('Reading abort')); 
    };

    reader.onload = function () {
        self._log("load");
    };

    reader.onloadstart = function () {
        self._log("start");
    };

    reader.onprogress = function () {
        self.log("progress");
    };

    try {
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } catch (e) {
        self._log(e);   
    }
};
```

At first I thought this was a failure to define some objects:

```
    if (!FileReader) FileReader = window.FileReader  || null;
    if (!requestFileSystem) requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem || null;
    if (!File) File = window.File || null;

    if (!FileReader || !File) 
        throw new Error("Objects of file API does not exists!");
```

But debugging, I realize that all variables are what they should be:

[debug http://esfriki.com/f/wtf.min.png](http://esfriki.com/f/wtf.min.png)

> **Update**: I edit this, but finnaly this does not because the minify, this is an error what ocurr randomly when I build.

Comment: Anytime ;) I am about to leave work, but will take a look at this when I get home if no one has answered you yet.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?  Could it have something to do with the change of CoFS to c?

Comment: This runs on a cordova app, I'm using require.js and "compile" it with a grunt task. The problem is where I set the "optimize" option to uglify2. Is the only that fails.